# List of table header appears in the other sections?

Tags: pdftex, header-footer

I'm typing my thesis and when I add list of tables to the main code I realized that the header of list of tables appear in the next page of the introduction (introduction générale), I didn't have this problem before adding `\chapter*{Introduction générale}`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage[arabic,frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\definecolor{GrisF}{rgb}{105,105,105}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=3cm,rmargin=2cm,headheight=18pt}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}

\begin{document}

\section*{Dédicace}
\vspace{15mm}
\input{dedicace}
\newpage


\section*{Remerciement}
\vspace{15mm}
\input{remerciement}
\newpage

\section*{Résumé}
\vspace{15mm}
\input{abstrait}
\newpage

\includepdf[pages=-]{molakhas.pdf}

\section*{Abstract}
\vspace{15mm}
\input{abstract}
\newpage

% Tables des matières/Figures
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\listoffigures
\newpage
\listoftables
\newpage


\chapter*{Introduction générale}
\vspace{10mm}
\input{intro}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Introduction générale}
\newpage

\chapter{Analyse des sentiments}
\input{chapitre1}

\chapter{Apprentissage profond}
\input{chapitre2}

\chapter{Conception de système}
\input{chapitre3}

\chapter{Implémentation}
\input{chapitre4}

\chapter*{Conclusion générale}
\vspace{10mm}
\input{conclusion}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Conclusion générale}
\newpage


%\includepdf[pages=-]{biblio.pdf}

\medskip

\bibliographystyle{plain}

\bibliography{bibl}


\end{document}
```

Is there something I can do to correct this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Thank you,  i added all the main tex content, but it's not compilable since it requires the input files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution with a simplified example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage[arabic,frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\definecolor{GrisF}{rgb}{105,105,105}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=3cm,rmargin=2cm,headheight=18pt}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}

\usepackage{lipsum} % seulement pour cet exemple 

\begin{document}

% Tables des matières/Figures
\tableofcontents
%\newpage %pas besoin de ça, si vous voulez que le chapitre commence toujours dans une page impaire, ajoutez "openright" aux options du document
\listoffigures
%\newpage
\listoftables
%\newpage


\chapter*{Introduction générale}
\markboth{Introduction générale}{Introduction générale}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction générale} 
%\vspace{10mm}
\lipsum[1-5]


\chapter{Un autre chapitre}

\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
         &  \\
         & 
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}


\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
         &  \\
         & 
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
         &  \\
         & 
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
         &  \\
         & 
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}

\lipsum[1-5]


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you it worked for me but  the line \lipsum[1-5] changed my introudction with 5 lines of lipsum, the solution is just by adding :

Comment: @Katty, yes, lipsum is just filler (dummy) text in case it was necessary to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Just to make it clear, the command `\markboth` makes the difference.